# iTerm2 and VI key mappings

Tags: key-bindings, macos, iterm2

I am trying to use a few keys and key combinations with `VI` (`VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2`) running in `iTerm2` `3.4.15` with `zsh` on `macOS Monterey 12.1` on the `Apple M1 Max` chip. So far, I tried to set `nocompatible` and use `map` in both `.vimrc` and active environment, all to no avail.

I would like to set up the following key bindings:

- `Home`/`End` keys for beginning and end of the line.
- `Ctrl+<arrow left/right>` to jump one word left or right.
- `Delete` to delete the character.
- `Insert` to switch to insert mode.

Is there a plugin I could install? Or a settings file?

### Update

Some of the keys or combinations don't do anything at all; others have odd behaviors such as:
*Normal Mode:*

- `End` scrolls down one line at a time.
- `Home` increases numerical values if cursor is located to the left of a number, but not to the right. Otherwise it does nothing.

*Insert Mode:*

- `Home` copies characters and/or lines; not sure exactly what is the actual copy rule.
- `End` copies only characters.
- `Delete` deletes empty space from the beginning of the line, if any, otherwise, it does nothing.

### Update 2

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

### Update 3

`:verbose set term?` returns `term=xterm-256color` which is the same value as `$TERM`.

The sequences the keys produce are different. The normal mode has `*` and the insert mode has a `5` instead.

```
:set <Home>
t_kh <Home>      ^[[1;*H

INSERT
Ctrl+V, Ctrl+Home
^[[1;5H

Ctrl+V, Home
^A


:set <End>
t_@7 <End>       ^[[1;*F

INSERT
Ctrl+V, Ctrl+End
^[[1;5F

Ctrl+V, End
^E
```

### Update 4

I ended up resetting *iTerm2* to its default settings and I figured out the root cause.
As default, `Ctrl + <left/right arrows>` key combinations do not work, as well as the `Home` and `End` keys. At the same time, in *VI*, these key combinations work in both normal and insert modes.

If I add these keys and combinations to *iTerm2* *Key Binding* and profile *Key Mappings* they work for *iTerm2* but stop working for *VI*.

Following is the default behavior for both iTerm2 and VI:

iTerm2

- Ctrl + <left/right arrow> does not work
- Home, End do not work

vi
*-> Normal Mode*

- `Ctrl + <left/right arrow>` works
- `Home`, `End` work
- `Backspace` moves back
- `Del` works

*-> Insert Mode*

- `Ctrl + <left/right arrow>` works
- `Home`, `End` work
- `Ctrl + w` does not work
- `Backspace` does not work
- `Del` works
- can not delete `\n`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132792/discussion-on-question-by-slybloty-iterm2-and-vi-key-mappings).